# how add css,js in html files with spring mvc 4

Tags: css, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm having difficulty importing my CSS files with spring 4

First i tried this in index.html

```
<link  href="../../resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Eclipse did not acknowledge any errors, but when I run the application the css does not load on the page

After searching i did this

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
```

And in index.html I left it like that, and it worked

```
<link  href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the eclipse says there is an error
[look this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSATL.png)

[my classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3Wel.png)

statics

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/html/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController( "/" ).setViewName( "forward:/index.html" );

    }
```

1)What is the correct way to import CSS and JS and spring 4?

2)Why the first way did not work? using ../../

3)How to import without eclipse accuse error?

thanks guys^^

Comment: try using <link  href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Here you can find my answer with the same problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53125816/9918701

Answer (score 0):

To My previous knowledge and errors make sure you are defining the correct directory and adding the right links. Hope that helped if not I am sorry.